# Divide elements of 1-D tensor by the corrispondent index

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, tensor

I'm using Tensorflow with python 2.7.

I  have a binary **1-D tensor** like this:

```
a = [ 1 , 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

I want compute the sum of the ratio of each elements of the tensor by the corrispondent index.

For example, i need to compute:

```
[ 1/1 + 0/2 + 1/3 + 0/4 + 0/5 ]
```

Is there a **Tensorflow** function that does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tf.shape` or as Dzjkb's answer `get_shape` to get the tensor size.

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
x = tf.constant([1,0,1,0,1])
y = tf.range(1, tf.shape(x)[0] + 1)
#y = tf.range(1, x.get_shape()[0].value + 1)
z = x / y
sess.run(z)
```

output:

```
array([ 1.        ,  0.        ,  0.33333333,  0.        ,  0.2       ])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tf.range](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/range) and the / operator, like

```
# a is your 1-D binary tensor
r = tf.range(1, a.get_shape()[0].value)
result = a / r
```

**Note:** a and r must be of the same type